# Issues assigning colors to numeric values ​of columns in Excel in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have this df:

```
             NOMBRE ESTACION DEPARTAMENTO  ... APNoviembre APDiciembre
0                   ARAMANGO     AMAZONAS  ...  -15.463042    3.254973
1                BAGUA CHICA     AMAZONAS  ...   -8.193005    7.855943
2                CHACHAPOYAS     AMAZONAS  ...  -11.803714   -9.552846
3                   CHIRIACO     AMAZONAS  ...         NaN         NaN
4                  EL PINTOR     AMAZONAS  ...     8.99654    10.01199
..                       ...          ...  ...         ...         ...
529                      ITE        TACNA  ...       500.0        25.0
530                 VILACOTA        TACNA  ...  -14.666667    2.389078
531                  LA CRUZ       TUMBES  ...  -26.666667      78.125
532  LAS PALMERAS DE UCAYALI      UCAYALI  ...    8.700102      6.0981
533            SAN ALEJANDRO      UCAYALI  ...  -23.723229   -24.59382

[534 rows x 20 columns]
```

I want to color only the numeric values in a determined range (columns from 9 to the final column) and export it to excel. So i did this code:

```
#Export the df to excel
with pd.ExcelWriter("path/to/file/df.xlsx") as writer:   
    df.to_excel(writer,'ANOM', index=False)


import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import pandas as pd
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("path/to/file/df.xlsx")
ws = wb.active #Name of the working sheet


fill_cell1 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='C2523C')
fill_cell2 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='E8951A')
fill_cell3 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='FAEA05')
fill_cell4 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='FFFFFF')
fill_cell5 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='B8F500')
fill_cell6 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='400000')
fill_cell7 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='19B04D')

fill_cell8 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='198759')
fill_cell9 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='089EAD')
fill_cell10 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='2B61A8')
fill_cell11 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='0B2C7A')
fill_cell12 = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                           fgColor='000000')

for row in ws.rows:
    for i in range(8,8+int((ws.max_column-8)/2)):
        if row[i].value > 800:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell11
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell11
        elif 400 <= row[i].value <= 800:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell10
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell10
        elif 200 <= row[i].value < 400:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell9
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell9
        elif 100 <= row[i].value < 200:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell8
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell8
        elif 60 <= row[i].value < 100:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell7
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell7
        elif 30 <= row[i].value < 60:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell6
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell6
        elif 15 <= row[i].value < 30:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell5
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell5
        elif -15 <= row[i].value < 15:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell4
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell4
        elif -30 <= row[i].value < -15:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell3
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell3
        elif -60 <= row[i].value < -30:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell2
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell2
        elif -100 <= row[i].value < -60:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell1
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell1
        elif row[i].value == "NaN" or row[i].value == "" or row[i].value == None:
            row[i].fill = fill_cell12
            row[int(i+(ws.max_column-8)/2)].fill = fill_cell12

wb.save("path/to/file/df_colored.xlsx")
```

but i got this error: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I know the error is because openpyxl is taking `row[i].value` as a string header, not a numeric value but i don't understand why. I replaced the 8 to 9, 10 or even 11 in `range(8,8+int((ws.max_column-8)/2))` and it only works with 19, but i dont get the excel file with the colors. Can someone help me to understand well the rows in a ws and give some solution to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on earth do people save to Excel and then open the same file in openpyxl? You can either use a writer object, or for the most control use `dataframe_to_rows()` to write directly into a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are trying to compare a string (the text in the column header) to a int (first check value 800) which gives the error.
Why don't you use iter_rows and skip the first row, so not have to worry about the headers?
However you are also expecting other string values 'NaN', "", and Empty cells so just skipping the Header will not avoid this error. Therefore you could check the cell value is a float or integer if so check the range for fill colour, if not apply the cell colour for strings.
**NOTE:** Using the cell type check means setting the `min_row` to 2 is unnecesary since a Header will be rejected by both criteria checks anyway, but it still saves looping a row.

Note also for checking cell is None dont use '==' the syntax should be;

```
cell.value is None
```

To reduce the amount of lines I have changed cell fill colour operation to use a dictionary and function rather than setting multiple PatternFill lines.

```
...
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("path/to/file/df.xlsx")
ws = wb.active  # Name of the working sheet

def add_colour(cell, colour):
    ### fill cell based on the colour key
    cell.fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=colour)


### Create colour dictionary
colour_dict = {1: 'C2523C', 2: 'E8951A', 3: 'FAEA05', 4: 'FFFFFF',
               5:'B8F500', 6: '400000', 7: '19B04D', 8: '198759',
               9: '089EAD', 10: '2B61A8', 11: '0B2C7A', 12: '000000'}

### loop rows in columns skipping row 1
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=9, max_col=8+int((ws.max_column-8)/2), min_row=2):
    for cell in row:
        c_value = cell.value
        ### Check if the cell value is integer or float
        ### If so check the value range and set fill colour 
        if isinstance(c_value, (int, float)):
            if c_value > 800:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[11])
            elif 400 <= c_value <= 800:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[10])
            elif 200 <= c_value < 400:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[9])
            elif 100 <= c_value < 200:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[8])
            elif 60 <= c_value < 100:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[7])
            elif 30 <= c_value < 60:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[6])
            elif 15 <= c_value < 30:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[5])
            elif -15 <= c_value < 15:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[4])
            elif -30 <= c_value < -15:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[3])
            elif -60 <= c_value < -30:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[2])
            elif -100 <= c_value < -60:
                add_colour(cell, colour_dict[1])

        ### This elif is on the same level as the int float test
        ### If cell value is not int or float check the following strings or empty cell 
        elif c_value == "NaN" or c_value == "" or c_value is None:
            add_colour(cell, colour_dict[12])

wb.save("path/to/file/df_colored.xlsx")
```

Comment: A dictionary of fills would be easier and faster. And I'd split the max_col calculation into a separate line to make it easier to debug or change. But I'd also be tempted to do everything with conditional format and let Excel do the work.

Comment: You could also use a dict keyed with the bounds and the fill and avoid all the error prone branching. `fills = {(400, 800):fills[11],…}`

Comment: @moken i got this error TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Cell' and i tried to know the type of the cell variable using: type(cell) and i got this:
Out[5]: openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell

Comment: @Javier Yep, looks like the cell value variable did not update for the -60 to -30 and -100 to -60 criteria checks so these were cell objects rather than the cell value. I have updated these two variables in the code example above